# Stop recording audio when recording video in Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

Has anyone disabled sound in either Intent or MediaRecorder when record video in Google
Glass?

I have removed permissions from AndroidManifest and I am not setting the audio source in MediaRecorder but I still record audio.

I am using XE22.

```
    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
    }       
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if (mCamera == null) return false;

    mrec = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();

    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
    //mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    CamcorderProfile profile = getValidCamcorderProfile();

    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mrec.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mrec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);

    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(mPreviewHolder.getSurface());

    mOutputFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    mrec.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.toString());

    try {
        mrec.prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private CamcorderProfile getValidCamcorderProfile(){
    CamcorderProfile profile;

    if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_720P)){
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_720P);
        return profile;
    }

    if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P))
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
    else
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    return profile;
}
```

The code is taken from the book Beginning Google Glass Development.
Any Ideas??

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Post the recording code you have now and I can help you. This will benefit other people too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution that  worked before for me few years ago but my code is now crashing due to several API updates.  Withing hours of try and fail experiment, I got it to start working again.

Steps:

**1)** Remove anything about audio such as ***setVideoSource*** and ***setAudioEncoder***. From the code you posted above. It looks like you already did that but verify that from the rest of your code.

**2)** Add try catch to setProfile and you are fine to go. 
  For example:
Instead of doing `mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH))`

do:

```
try {
    mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
}catch (Exception e){

}
```

Furthermore, don't use `CamcorderProfile profile = getValidCamcorderProfile();`. Use  `mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH))` and that should work.
Also remove the following from your code

**`mrec.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);, mrec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);, mrec.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);.`**

Inside my ***prepareVideoRecorder()*** function, this is what my code looks like:

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
    }
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if (mCamera == null) return false;

    mrec = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();

    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
    //mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER); Remove this
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    //Add try catch to setProfile
    try {
     mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(mPreviewHolder.getSurface());

    mOutputFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    mrec.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.toString());

    try {
        mrec.prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To **see** the **recorded** video on **Glass** from your **computer**, you have to **restart Glass**.

EDIT:
Get my whole project from [here](https://github.com/InnoBlast/RecordingVideoWithoutSound). Its from the book and was modified to record without audio.
https://github.com/InnoBlast/RecordingVideoWithoutSound

Comment: I works for me. I tested it about 10 times and it worked each time. It records with no sound. You probably missed a step. I just provided a link so that you can download my whole project that is working. Let me know if it worked....

Comment: I have just run your code and still my Glass records sound.

Comment: That's weird because it is working on my XE22 Glass. When you run the code I posted above, how did you start to record the video? What did you press on Glass?

Comment: It is really weird. I am pressing the button for long press.
I have not seen in the logs any "onLongPress" line: 172 or "before start" line 177. The line numbers are from your code as neither this code is muting my video capture.

`code`